# Why does stopping apachectl break the Dock on MacOs Mojave?

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

Some strange things happens when I execute

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

on my MacBook Pro with MacOs Mojave.

No error message in the Terminal, but after execution of that command:

- Cmd+Tab stops working (just makes 'bip'-sounds when pressed, no list of apps, no switching between the apps),
- pressing any active icons in Dock forces it to stop and cannot be reopened again,
- menu on the top (Mac menu, programs menu) becomes not clickable.

Only reboot helps.

Does anyone has any ideas about the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Why are you trying to stop the service to begin with?

Comment: Looks like some problem happened with the Apache on my mac (trying to open localhost in browser fails) which I didn't used for around month. I decided to install Apache by brew, followed instructions here – https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions.
To check if apache is running already I tried "sudo apachectl start" and it said that httpd is working already. Then I tried to stop it.

Comment: `apachectl` usually points to the system's Apache server that shouldn't even show anything on your localhost. Please [edit] your question to include exactly what you have done including the steps from the tutorial.